# What is the proper way to test a Facebook Messenger app so that it recieves data?

Tags: facebook

To begin with I have never developed anything that interacts with Facebook before so please assume I don't know something unless I state otherwise.

I have a webhook that should in theory get hit every time someone sends me a message thru a page I have setup on Facebook.  I have the page setup and I have it linked to my app in the developer console.

The problem is I can't seem to figure out how to get any real data to come thru. I understand I can't acttualy send REAL data (I haven't submitted the app because I only want to test with it. The submitted version will be on a tottaly seperate Facebook account when I'm done.), but as long as it looks like the real stuff that is fine. (I print it out and all I get is a empty dictionary since I work with Python if it matters)

It seems like I need to make a test user and have them make a page and somehow link that to the app. Can't figure out how to link it though. It only shows my origional account's pages.

Maybe I'm going about this the entirely wrong way, but either way please help me clarify what I must do. It would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake.  It ended up being a issue with my Python. I was assuming the data was 
going to be thru the arguments aka:

```
request_args = request.args.to_dict(True)
```

Instead I needed the request as a json:

```
json_request = request.json
```